# Derive indices of range of applied attributes from AttributedString in Java

Tags: java, text, attributes

I need to get the indices of applied attributes on AttributedString.

So assume, you have a AttributedString with applied attributes, in my case subscript / superscript.

```
 AttributedString as1 = new AttributedString("1234567890");
 as1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 7);
```

I managed already to get the first character, where sub/superscript begins, via

```
        int startIdx = as1.getIterator().getRunLimit(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT);
```

At last i need to derive the endIdx of the applied attribute, but i couldnt find a way to solve this.
Even in the related java documentation, the method documentation says, that always the first character index is returned. Is there no way to get the endindex of applied attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have been found a pretty ugly way to solve this..
For those, who are interested:

```
   AttributedString as1 = new AttributedString("0123456789");
   as1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 6, 9);

   AttributedCharacterIterator it = string.getIterator();

   int startIdx = -1, endIdx = -1;

   while(it.current() != AttributedCharacterIterator.DONE) {
        boolean attributeExists = (Integer) it.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT) != null ? true : false;
        if (attributeExists && startIdx == -1)
            startIdx = it.getIndex();

        if (attributeExists && startIdx != -1)
            endIdx = it.getIndex();

        it.next();
    }
```

I think this solution works only for single applied attribute on AttributedStrings. For my case, this is suitable enough.
I wont accept my answer, because i would be interested in a more elegant way to do the same.